# Send C# App Via Email

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, email-attachments

I need to send my C# app in an email for a job interview exercise. It says to save the exercise as a zip file and email it. I would have thought they wanted to see the code, but just looking now, it looks like the only way to do this is to zip the .exe file and send it. The code will not be visible to them? Any way to show the code? Add my .cs file to the email?

Comment: They dont probably need the exe .Just zip ur code and send them

Comment: This isn't directly programming related, it would have been a better fit for http://www.SuperUser.com

Comment: @JeremyThompson Thank you, i got confused because the number one hot question is "Why is there a clock on my desktop". I see now that is a different Stack Exchange website (which i did not know existed).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just zip the whole project directory? That will include your code files and your compiled .exe file. It will also include the solution or project from Visual Studio so they can open it on their end.

You may still need to change the extension of you executable file to something like `.exe1` before zipping, otherwise the email service might not let it through.

Comment: Or if exes are blocked, let them compile it themselves.  Also, look at dotNet Peek, there's ways to view underlying code in .Net assemblies

Comment: True. You could also rename the .exe to .exe1 before zipping, this will let it pass through at least gmail. It'll also possibly work with other services.

Comment: Cool! Didn't know Google only screened the .exe extension.  Thought they'd be a regex rather than a blacklist.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how it works internally, I just know that previously doing what I described would allow an .exe to be sent.

Comment: Thanks, I did that first and it does not work. It complains that you cannot send executable files in email. Why is this voted down? I did try that, then went to the MSDN website for the solution which i talked about in my question. Seems i have done some research and tried some things.

Comment: Sounds a bit...fragile!

Comment: It's not enough to just rename the .exe, you have to then still zip it.

Comment: This does not work. I have changed the .exe file extension to .exe1, then zipped the projectName folder. It is not allowed in email because it has an executable file. Should i delete the .exe file and will that ruin my program? They will have Visual Studio to view and run it

Comment: If it were me, I would `Clean` the solution in visual studio and then zip and send it. Cleaning removes generated files, but may also leave some ...vshost.exe files behind. In this case you would need to check inside the `bin\Debug` and `bin\Release` directories and remove those files manually before zipping.

Comment: Thanks. I may look into that but have some concerns about it changing my program. Since it is not so straight forward, i think i won't seem incompetent if i send the one zipped .exe for them to run, then either the .cs file as an email attachment if it is allowed, if not, copy paste the code from that file.

Comment: Cannot even send the zipped .exe file which is exactly what the MSDN website says to do. It said that in 2008 however. I guess email security is higher now.